Re-order 1 value of X-axis in GGPLOT
I have the following dataframe from which i created a GGPLOT
dataframe:
boxchart3 <- structure(list(Treatment = c("Referral to secondary care", "Watchful waiting", 
"Watchful waiting", "Referral to secondary care", "Post operation: control", 
"Injection (corticosteroid)", "Post operation: removing sutures", 
"Additional examination", "Post operation: control", "Prescription for pain medication", 
"Additional examination", "To plan a physical contact", "Injection (corticosteroid)", 
"Post operation: removing sutures", "Referral to paramedical care", 
"Prescription for pain medication", "To plan a physical contact", 
"Referral to paramedical care", "Prescription for antibiotics or prednison", 
"Prescription for antibiotics or prednison", "Prescription for cutane creme", 
"Prescription for cutane creme"), Type = c("Total", "Total", 
"Sensitivity Analysis", "Sensitivity Analysis", "Total", "Total", 
"Total", "Total", "Sensitivity Analysis", "Total", "Sensitivity Analysis", 
"Total", "Sensitivity Analysis", "Sensitivity Analysis", "Total", 
"Sensitivity Analysis", "Sensitivity Analysis", "Sensitivity Analysis", 
"Total", "Sensitivity Analysis", "Total", "Sensitivity Analysis"
), Number = c(1540L, 1434L, 732L, 591L, 175L, 124L, 122L, 87L, 
67L, 56L, 54L, 53L, 51L, 47L, 38L, 29L, 26L, 15L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 
3L), Percentage = c(37.6804502079765, 35.0868607780768, 40.5764966740577, 
32.7605321507761, 4.28186934181551, 3.03401027648642, 2.98507462686567, 
2.12870075850257, 3.7139689578714, 1.37019818938096, 2.99334811529933, 
1.29679471494984, 2.82705099778271, 2.60532150776053, 0.929777342794226, 
1.60753880266075, 1.44124168514412, 0.831485587583148, 0.318081722534867, 
0.498891352549889, 0.171274773672621, 0.16629711751663)), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = "data.frame")

I've used the following script to create a GGPLOT.
box <- ggplot(boxchart3) +
        geom_bar( aes(x = reorder(Treatment, Number), y=Percentage, fill = Type, group = Type),
                  stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
        geom_text( aes(x=reorder(Treatment, Number), y= Percentage, label =Number, group = Type),
                   hjust = -0.25, size =2.3,
                   position = position_dodge(width = 1),
                   inherit.aes = TRUE) +
        coord_flip() +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(legend.position = "bottom",
              legend.title = element_blank(),
              legend.text = element_text(color = "gray33"),
              axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, color = "gray33"),
              axis.text.y = element_text(color = "gray33"),
              axis.title = element_text(color = "gray33"), 
              panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
        labs(y = "Percentage (%)", x = "Treatment")

This script shows the following plot

The result is almost what i desired, but i would like to order the X-axis value based on the 'Total' number values (see plot below). My aim is to order the X-axis in ascending order (from high to low) based on the 'Total' number values.
Desired output (created by @Stefan (many thanks for helping me btw!!)

As suggested, I've tried to change the order of the database by apply the following syntax to create the desired x-axis order.
boxchart3 <- boxchart3 %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = reorder(Treatment, -ifelse(Type == 'Total', Number, 0), FUN = sum)) |> 
  arrange(Treatment) 

boxchart3<- boxchart3 %>%
  arrange(fct_reorder2(as.factor(Treatment2), Number, Type,
                       .fun = \(x, y) x[y == 'Total']))

However, both of these options still give the same result when I apply this in the ggplot script.
If i change the GGPLOT script from
ggplot(boxchart3) +
        geom_bar( aes(x = reorder(Treatment, Number), y=Percentage, fill = Type, group = Type),
                  stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +....

to
ggplot(boxchart3) +
        geom_bar( aes(x = Treatment, y=Percentage, fill = Type, group = Type),
                  stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +....

leads to:

This changes the order of the X-axis, but now they are in a ascending order, but my aim is to have them in descending order.
I cant seem to figure it out and its doing my head in!

See e.g. Reorder variable according to conditions for several options.

I've tried these options, but it still doesnt change the x-axis order on the plot.

Works fine for me: https://i.sstatic.net/T91PHJjW.png What did you map on x? x = Treatment?

Hmm, strange. This is exactly how i want it, but it doesnt show it for me. I've coded X like this: x = reorder(Treatment, Number). If I use x = Treatment, i get the x axis almost like desired (as your picture!), but only in ascending order (so referral as the lowest).
